# Recursive relations search between 2 columns in a table [Using python list / Dict]

Tags: python, optimization

I am trying to optimize a solution that I created to find recursive relations between 2 columns in a table. I need to find all accIDs for a bssID and recursively find all the bssIDs for those accIDs and so on till I find all the related bssIDs.

| bssIDs | accIDs |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 4424 |
| ABC | 56424 |
| ABC | 2383 |
| A100BC | 2383 |
| A100BC | 4943 |
| A100BC | 4880 |
| A100BC | 6325 |
| A100BC | 4424 |
| XYZ | 123 |

The below solution works for an initial table of 100K rows but the below solution runs for  >16 hours for a dataset of 20 million rows. I am trying to use dicts instead of list but I am unable to change the dict while iterating over the same as I am with a list.

```
import time

accIds = {4880: ['A100BC'], 6325: ['A100BC'], 2383: ['A100BC','ABC'],4424: ['A100BC','ABC'], 4943: ['A100BC'], 56424: ['ABC'],123: ['XYZ']}

bssIds = {'ABC': [4424,56424,2383], 'A100BC': [2383,4943,4880,6325,4424], 'XYZ':[123]}

def findBIDs(aID):
    return accIds[aID]
def findAIDs(bID):
    return bssIds[bID]
def getList(Ids):
    return Ids.keys()
def checkList(inputList, value):
    return (value in inputList)
def addToList(inputList, value):
    return inputList.append(value)
def removeFromList(inputList, value):
    return inputList.remove(value)
    
aIDlist = list(getList(accIds))
bIDlist = list(getList(bssIds))
bRelations = {}
runningList = list()
for x in bIDlist:
    if not checkList(runningList,x):
        aList = list()
        bList = list()
        addToList(bList, x)
        for y in bList:
            for c in findAIDs(y):
                if not checkList(aList, c):
                    addToList(aList, c)
            for z in aList:
                for a in findBIDs(z):
                    if not checkList(bList, a):
                        addToList(bList, a)
        bRelations.update({time.time_ns(): bList}) 
        runningList.extend(bList)
print(bRelations)

Output : {1652374114032173632: ['ABC', 'A100BC'], 1652374114032180888: ['XYZ']}
```

Please suggest if there is a way to update a dict while iterating over it or If we can apply a recursive solution for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fastest I could think of:

```
accIds = {4880: frozenset(['A100BC']), 6325: frozenset(['A100BC']), 2383: frozenset(['A100BC','ABC']),4424: frozenset(['A100BC','ABC']), 4943: frozenset(['A100BC']), 56424: frozenset(['ABC']),123: frozenset(['XYZ'])}
bssIds = {'ABC': frozenset([4424,56424,2383]), 'A100BC': frozenset([2383,4943,4880,6325,4424]), 'XYZ':frozenset([123])}

def search_bssid(bssId):
    traversed_accIds = set()
    traversed_bssIds = {bssId}
    accIds_to_check = []
    bssIds_to_check = [bssId]
    while bssIds_to_check:
        bssId = bssIds_to_check.pop()
        new_accids = bssIds[bssId] - traversed_accIds
        traversed_accIds.update(new_accids)
        accIds_to_check.extend(new_accids)
        while accIds_to_check:
            accId = accIds_to_check.pop()
            new_bssids = accIds[accId] - traversed_bssIds
            traversed_bssIds.update(new_bssids)
            bssIds_to_check.extend(new_bssids)
    return traversed_bssIds

print(search_bssid("ABC"))
```